# bitMapToFile ERR: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/image.jpg: open failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted) in android

Tags: android, kotlin, bitmap, converters, writetofile

I try code BitMapToFile but it has ERR!!

```
class ImageProcess {

    companion object {
        fun bitmapToFile(imageBitmap: Bitmap , filename: String): File? {
            val sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            val dest = File(sd, filename)

            try {
                val out = FileOutputStream(dest) //problem
                imageBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out)
                out.flush()
                out.close()
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }

            return dest

        }
    }

}
```

this ERR!

```
W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/image.jpg: open failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:492)
W/System.err:     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:236)
```

But I have `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"`
in file AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.TestFirst"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
```

Comment: What is the Android version of used device?

Comment: Galaxy S10+(android 11)

Comment: Yes you can not create files on /storage/emulated/0 on an Android 11 device. Try one of the public directories on it like Documents, Download and so on.